# Group rows in a multidimensional array and sum the "count" elements in each group

Tags: php, arrays, merge, sum, grouping

I have an array of associative arrays and I would like to group them by the rows by the values for `A`, `B`, and `C` and sum the `count` value for each group.

```
$array = [
    ['A' => 'O',    'B' => 'O',     'C' => 1, 'count' => 1],
    ['A' => 'Test', 'B' => 'Test',  'C' => 1, 'count' => 1],
    ['A' => 'O',    'B' => 'O',     'C' => 1, 'count' => 1],
    ['A' => 'Test', 'B' => 'Test',  'C' => 1, 'count' => 1],
    ['A' => 'Test', 'B' => 'test1', 'C' => 2, 'count' => 1],
];
```

I need a result like this:

```
[
    ["A" => "O",    "B" => "O",     "C" => 1, "count" => 2],
    ["A" => "Test", "B" => "Test",  "C" => 1, "count" => 2],
    ["A" => "Test", "B" => "test1", "C" => 2, "count" => 1]  
]
```

In order to make this you need to loop through the array and check where the attributes **"A", "B", "C"** are equal.  I tried doing this, but I couldn't fix it.

```
$countedArray[0] = $array[0];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $occKey = array_filter(
        $countedArray,
        function ($countedItem, $key) use ($array) {
            if ($countedItem['A'] == $item['A']
                && $countedItem['B'] == $item['B']
                && $countedItem['C'] == $item['C']
            ) {
                $countedItem[$key]['count'] = countedItem[$key]['count'] + 1
            } else {
                array_push(
                    $countedArray,
                    [
                        'A' => $item['A'],
                        'B' => $item['B'],
                        'C' => $item['C'],
                        'count' => 1
                    ]
                );
            }
        },
        ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done my best to make it less verbose. I welcome any suggestions. Here's my proposed solution:

```php
function sumOccurrences(array $original): array
{
    $summed = [];
    foreach ($original as $value) {
        // here we get the array without the 'count' key - everything we need to compare
        $comparisonElement = array_filter($value, function ($key) {
            return $key !== 'count';
        }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
        // we search with strict comparison (third param - true) - see reasoning below
        $foundAt = array_search($comparisonElement, array_column($summed, 'element'), true);
        if ($foundAt === false) {
            // we separate the values we compare and the count for easier handling
            $summed[] = ['element' => $comparisonElement, 'count' => $value['count']];
        } else {
            // if we've run into an existing element, just increase the count
            $summed[$foundAt]['count'] += $value['count'];
        }
    }

    // since we separated count from the values for comparison, we have to merge them now
    return array_map(function ($a) {
        // $a['count'] is wrapped in an array as it's just an integer
        return array_merge($a['element'], ['count' => $a['count']]);
    }, $summed);
}
```

In order to make it less verbose, I've opted to compare arrays directly. Other than being less verbose, another benefit is that this will work if additional key => value pairs are introduced to the array without any addition to logic. Everything that is not `count` gets compared, no matter how many pairs exist. It will also cover any nested arrays (for example `'C' => ['D' => 1]`).

But, this comes at a price - we must use strict comparison because loose can give undesired results (for example, `['a'] == [0]` will return `true`). Strict comparison also means that it won't work if any values are objects (strict comparison means it's checking for the same *instance*) and that arrays will only be matched if they have the same key => value pairs *in the same order*. This solution assumes that your array (and any nested ones) are already sorted.

If that is not the case, we'd have to sort it before comparing. Normally, `ksort` would do the job, but to support nested arrays, we'd have to devise a recursive sort by key:

```php
function ksortRecursive(array &$array): void
{
    ksort($array);
    foreach ($array as &$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            ksortRecursive($value);
        }
    }
}
```

and call it before we do `array_search`.

Now if we assume a starting array like in your example, the following should give you the desired result:

```php
$original = [
    ['A' => 'O', 'B' => 'O', 'C' => 1, 'count' => 1],
    ['A' => 'Test', 'B' => 'Test', 'C' => 1, 'count' => 1],
    ['A' => 'O', 'B' => 'O', 'C' => 1, 'count' => 1],
    ['A' => 'Test', 'B' => 'Test', 'C' => 1, 'count' => 1],
    ['A' => 'Test', 'B' => 'test1', 'C' => 2, 'count' => 1],
];
var_dump(sumOccurrences($original));
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is working waaaaay too hard for what is a basic task.

You merely need to use temporary, composite keys (based on the first three elements' values) to form grouped results.  When a new row matches a pre-existing group, simply add its `count` to the stored `count` for the group. When the loop finishes, call `array_values()` to re-index the first level of the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/a0Cfa))

```
$array = [
    ['A' => 'O', 'B' => 'O', 'C' => 1, 'count' => 1],
    ['A' => 'Test', 'B' => 'Test', 'C' => 1, 'count' => 1],
    ['A' => 'O', 'B' => 'O', 'C' => 1, 'count' => 1],
    ['A' => 'Test', 'B' => 'Test', 'C' => 1, 'count' => 1],
    ['A' => 'Test', 'B' => 'test1', 'C' => 2, 'count' => 1],
];

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $key = implode('~', array_slice($row, 0, 3));
    if (!isset($result[$key])) {
        $result[$key] = $row;
    } else {
        $result[$key]['count'] += $row['count'];
    }
}

var_export(array_values($result));
```